# Azure devops framework 4.6 pipeline build error

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild-4.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2601,5): error : Copying file Rotativa\wkhtmltopdf.exe to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Rotativa\wkhtmltopdf.exe failed. Could not find a part of the path 'Rotativa\wkhtmltopdf.exe'. [D:\a\1\s\ERP.csproj]

While building the application using azure devops pipeline it is throwing this error. Normal build is working but this portion is throwing the error.
msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'

I need a solution for this error.